# Flutter - remove a Realtime Firebase Data onTap()

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have a ListView, filled with different addresses of same user stored at Firebase Realtime Database.on tap of specific item I show a alert dialog, requesting confirmation of deleting the address. I want to delete the address from firebase database when user agreed to delete it.

**Here is Snippet of onTap of the specific item:**

```
onTap: (){

        if(widget.paymentFlag==true) {
          if (addressList[index].Pin ==
              widget.userPin) {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    PaymentPage(
                      Pin: widget.userPin,)
            ));
          }
          else {
            _scaffoldKey.currentState
                .showSnackBar(
                new SnackBar(
                  behavior: SnackBarBehavior
                      .floating,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  duration: new Duration(
                      seconds: 2),
                  content:
                  new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[

                      Icon(FontAwesomeIcons
                          .exclamation,
                        color: Colors.black,),
                      SizedBox(width: 10,),
                      new Text(
                        "Item not deliverable to this address",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight
                                .w700,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle
                                .italic,
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: Colors.black
                        ),)
                    ],
                  ),
                ));
          }
        }else{
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
            // return object of type Dialog
            return AlertDialog(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              title: new Text("Remove this Address",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
              content: new Text(addressList[index].Line1+"\n"+addressList[index].City+"\n"+addressList[index].Pin,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
              actions: <Widget>[
                // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
                new FlatButton(
                  child: new Text("Close"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
                new FlatButton(
                  child: new Text("OK"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('AllUsers').child(widget.userNumber).child('Address');
   
  ///////////Here I want to delete the element///////////////////////////////////////////////

                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for [`DatabaseReference.remove()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DatabaseReference/remove.html)?

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()
                         .child('AllUsers')
                         .child(widget.userNumber)
                         .child('Address')
                         .remove();
```

You may want to only navigate away once the data has been removed from the database on the server, in which case you'd do":

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()
                         .child('AllUsers')
                         .child(widget.userNumber)
                         .child('Address')
                         .remove()
                         .then(() {
                             Navigator.of(context).pop();
                         })
```

Comment: I want to delete the specific address user tapped on. The Node of Address consists of many address with different keys. I afraid if I use the above one then it will delete all my addresses.

Comment: You'll need to know the key of the address to remove in that case, and then insert that in the chain.... `.reference().child('AllUsers').child(widget.userNumber).child('Address').child(keyOfTheSpecificAddressToRemove).remove()`

Comment: Hey @Frank van Puffelen, This post was helpful but didn't give the exact answer to my question. Sorry I forget to give Upvote to this answer.